# FullCalendar on loading > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

thanks for tyour assistance first of all.
I'm simply loading FullCalendar (https://fullcalendar.io/) on my dev environemts but it doesn't seem to work.

When I open the console on Chrome it gives me the following issue.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at fullcalendar.min.js:6
    at fullcalendar.min.js:6
    at fullcalendar.min.js:6
```

I haven't even called/declared the script yet and this puzzles me.

Code cut down to the essential below. Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">

        <!-- CSS -->
        <link href="http://localhost/dev/assets/third-party/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="http://localhost/dev/assets/third-party/css/skins/indianred.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.2.0/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <link href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.2.0/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />

    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- WRAPPER -->
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="calendar"></div>

        </div>
        <!-- END WRAPPER -->
        <!-- JAVASCRIPTS -->
        <script src='http://localhost/dev/assets/third-party/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js'></script>
        <script src='http://localhost/dev/assets/third-party/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
        <script src='http://localhost/dev/assets/third-party/js/repute-scripts.js'></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.9/validator.min.js"></script>
        <script src='http://localhost/dev/assets/third-party/js/plugins/moment/moment.min.js'></script>
        <script src='http://localhost/dev/assets/third-party/js/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
        <script src="http://localhost/dev/assets/js/b/result.js"></script>
        <script src="http://localhost/dev/assets/js/b/event.js"></script>
        <script src="http://localhost/dev/assets/js/b/bapp.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                var bapp = new Bapp();
            });
        </script>
        <!-- END JAVASCRIPTS -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it is not clear what you are doing here `var bapp = new Bapp();`

Comment: that doesn't matter. I commeted it out and the error is still there.

Comment: Only when I comment out the call to the fullcalendar.min.js then the error disappears.

Comment: Could you organise a fiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error message because I using a version of `moment` that didn't support `moment.momentProperties`.  If you point to `fullcalendar.js` instead of the min version, the line numbers in the error message will help you see whether or not the error originated from the same issue. I fixed it by downloading the zip file from `fullcalendar` and pointing to the `moment.min.js` file included there. I was using `moment version 2.0.0`. The version included from `fullcalendar` (downloaded today) was `2.18.1`.

Comment: Have you any ideas how to solve this if I want to use npm package for fullcalendar, jquery and moment(I have the same error)? The versione that I use are: fullcalendar: 3.10.0, moment 2.24.0, jquery 3.3.1