# Fullcalendar error moment properties.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, fullcalendar, momentjs

I have followed the docs of **fullcalendar** for loading the code with npm package. I have downloaded these 3 npm package:

- fullcalendar 3.10.0
- moment 2.24.0
- Jquery 3.3.1

I have initialize the calendar, but an error occours in console `moment moment.momentProperties.push is not a function`.

[image]

Follow this response https://stackoverflow.com/a/43771018/5384016, if i use cdns works fine, but i want to use npm package modules

Cdns scripts

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
```

This is my code

```
import ....;
import moment from 'moment';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'fullcalendar';

class CalendarEl extends React.PureComponent {
    componentDidMount() {
        $(`#calendar-1`).fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek',
            },
            themeSystem: 'bootstrap4',
            ....other opts
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Row className="calendar-row">
                <Col>
                    <div id={`calendar-1`} />
                </Col>
            </Row>
        );
    }
}

export default CalendarEl;
```

Someone can help me and show how to initialize full calendar with npm packages.I can't understand why if i use the same version of these 3 packages with cdns works fine

I also use webpack, I don't know if this is relevant

Comment: is the version of moment correct?

Comment: @DanOswalt yes, is the last release of moment. In package.json i can see:     "moment": "^2.24.0",

Comment: which version were the cdns that worked? possibly fullcalendar expects an older version's api?

Comment: the comments in the other one show that they got it to work using version 2.0.0, so perhaps trying setting that explicitly in you package.json

Comment: @DanOswalt i use the same version also in cdns <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>

Comment: hm, my only other idea would be to check if npm actually installed that version, if you do `npm list moment` in your project directory it should show what it downloaded

Comment: @DanOswalt the results is:                                                                                      
   `  | +-- chart.js@2.7.3 `
 ` | | -- moment@2.24.0  deduped `
` | -- moment@2.24.0  deduped `
` +-- moment@2.24.0 `
 ` -- react-dates@18.5.0 `
  ` -- react-moment-proptypes@1.6.0 `
    `-- moment@2.24.0  deduped  `

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was using Vite, and was able to resolve this exact issue by adding an alias in my bundler configuration:

```js
import {defineConfig} from 'vite';
import * as path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            moment: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/moment/moment.js'),
        },
    },
    // ...
```